# ALB Ingress Controller, Terminating TLS via AWS ACM. How to go End-To-End?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress, lets-encrypt, aws-application-load-balancer

We currently use the AWS ALB Ingress Controller to front out ingress, and terminate SSL using a certificate from AWS ACM.  This work fine.

Is there a way, to also encrypt the traffic from the Load balancer to the cluster?

Here is what I attempted

1. Install/Configure Cert Manager
2. Add a TLS Secret to the Ingress
3. Change the ingress annotation to set the backend protocol to HTTPS `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS`

This... results in a 502 gateway error

here is my current, working ingress, with only the relevant parts still shown.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: real-cert-arn
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: public.monitor
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order: "40"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: monitoring-public-qa
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-FS-1-2-Res-2020-10
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: cert-manager-r53-qa
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
spec:
  rules:
  - host: goldilocks.qa.realdomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: goldilocks-dashboard
            port:
              name: http
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - goldilocks.qa.realdomain.com
    secretName: goldilocks-qa-cert
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: real-lb-address.us-gov-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

my (staging) cert exists, and appears fine.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-17-2-102 ~]$ kubectl get cert -n goldilocks goldilocks-qa-cert -o yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: goldilocks-qa-cert
  namespace: goldilocks
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: Ingress
    name: goldilocks-dashboard
    uid: 2494e5be-e624-471b-afd3-c8d56f5dc853
  resourceVersion: "81003934"
  uid: d494a1ec-7509-474e-b154-d5db8ceb86c0
spec:
  dnsNames:
  - goldilocks.qa.realdomain.com
  issuerRef:
    group: cert-manager.io
    kind: ClusterIssuer
    name: cert-manager-r53-qa
  secretName: goldilocks-qa-cert
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2023-02-08T16:06:56Z"
    message: Certificate is up to date and has not expired
```

The fact I can not figure out what to google to find this answer, leads me to think that I'm attempting to do something weird?  I understand I could just terminate the TLS on the pod, but I didn't want to rely on the lets encrypt to provide me good/valid certs, I just want the traffic encrypted.